# How to change HomeAsUp indicator in new AppCompat Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I wanna change default ActionBar homeAsUp indicator (drawable) in my AppCompat Toolbar. How to achieve that?
Only default arrow shows up.

styles (same for other API's level):

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/home</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/home</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar in my fragment layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:homeAsUpIndicator="@drawable/home"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

In Fragment:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To change icon just call at runtime:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.home);
```

Trick with styles/themes not working.

[How to enable homeAsUp or call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() on standalone toolbar with appcompat v21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732952/how-to-enable-homeasup-or-call-setdisplayhomeasupenabled-on-standalone-toolbar)

Comment: Sigh. I had to attempt 10 other things before I found this... so simple. Thanks @daser

Comment: Note toolbar.setNavigationIcon doesn't work with setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

Comment: Use below code for appcompat v21 -->
 ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Enable
 actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white); //Change Icon

Answer (score 19):

I tried `setHomeAsUpIndicator(int resId)` ,it works.

```
private void initToolbar ( Toolbar mToolbar ) {

    mToolbar.setTitleTextColor ( getResources ().getColor ( R.color.main_title ) );
    setSupportActionBar ( mToolbar );

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar ();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled ( true );
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator ( R.drawable.ic_action_back );
}
```

But `mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back)` doesn't work :(

Answer (score 19):

Just add this line to your styles.xml

```
        <item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_back_arrow</item>
```

Comment: As per August 2016, this is the most correct answer. This way, you have a single place in which to change the icon, plus with the added bonus of not having to call the dreaded `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Comment: It worked for me but I think this will work only if you are using `Toolbar`. I set this in my theme.xml and it took effect everywhere in the app.

Answer (score 9):

If android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle used together with DrawerLayout and Toolbar you can change homeAsUp icon with the following code:

```
//set home as up indicator
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_up_indicator);

//remove home as up indicator
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
```

to show homeAsUpIndicator indicator instead of home indicator do following:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Docs:

[ActionBarDrawerToggle#setHomeAsUpIndicator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int))
[ActionBarDrawerToggle#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean))

Answer (score 4):

i just found out that it actually works 
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back)
and here is the code to make it work.

```
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   .....
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
```

Post the following code in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   ......
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Note Mainactivity in this code is the current activity i want my back or home button to go to. I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if this style line is used in a commonly shared AppCompat ToolBar/App bar with other activities in the App, including the main activity, the "**navigationIcon**" specified will be automatically shown, unlike the standard default *HomeAsUpIndicator*, which is not shown unless explicitly **enabled** as desired in an Activity, typically as follows: (in the *onCreate()*)

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

With the above style line, since it behaves in an opposite manner, in a similar fashion, the indicator needs to be explicitly **disabled** if it is not desired to be shown, as on the main activity, as follows: (in the *onCreate()*)

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

(as observed on Android 4.0.4, 4.3, and 4.4.2 phones)