# Android ActionBar disappears after signing apk

Tags: android, apk, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am facing an issue with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme which am not sure if it is a bug or something am not doing right.

This is how I have defined my app theme:

```
        <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo"></style>

<style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColour</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColour</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then offcouse I have this applied on to the app in the manifest as follows:

```
   <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo">
    ...
    </application>
```

This works well when I run the app from the IDE straight to my phone or emulator and it has an actionbar.

But once I generate a signed APK; the app losses the actionbar.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here?

This is my actiivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements
    NewsFragment.OnTenderItemSelectedListener,
    ProjectFragment.OnProjectItemSelectedListener,
    JobsFragment.Callbacks,
    JobsFragment.OnJobSelectedListener,
    PublicTenderFragment.OnTenderItemSelectedListener,
    PrivateSectorTendersFragment.OnTenderSelectedListener,
    CountyDocsFragment.Callbacks, BlogsFragment.OnBlogItemSelectedListener,
    MyCountyInfoFragment.Callbacks, PollsFragment.OnPollSelectedListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


private Handler handler;

private static final String STATE_KEY_COUNTY = "com.governanceapp.STATE_KEY_COUNTY";
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
public List<String> mListNameItem;

private ArrayList<FilterSpinner> mCounties = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
private ArrayList<FilterSpinner> mSectors = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();

private int mSelectedCounty = 0;
private int mSelectedSector = 0;
private int mSelectedCountyInfoType = 1;

private String mCountyToRestore = "";

// custom configurations
private long mBackPressed;
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000; // # milliseconds, desired
private static final int NAVDRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY = 250;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCountyToRestore = getIntent().hasExtra(STATE_KEY_COUNTY) ? savedInstanceState
                .getString(STATE_KEY_COUNTY) : "";
    }


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    handler = new Handler();


    /**
     * start with the news menu
     */
    displayView(R.id.nav_news);


}


public void displayView(int viewId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);


    switch (viewId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new GetStartedFragment();
            title = "Home";
            break;

        case R.id.nav_county_assembly:
            fragment = new MyCountyInfoFragment();
            title = "My County Info";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_news:
            fragment = new NewsListFragment();
            title = "News";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_development_projects:
            fragment = new ProjectsListFragment();
            title = "County Development Projects";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_jobs:
            fragment = new JobsFragment();
            title = "Jobs";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_public_tenders:
            fragment = new PublicTendersListFragment();
            title = "Public Sector Tenders";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_private_tenders:
            fragment = new PrivateSectorTendersFragment().newInstance(13);
            title = "Private Sectore Tenders";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_public_blogs:
            fragment = new BlogsFragment();
            title = "Blogs";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_county_docs:
            fragment = new CountyDocsFragment();
            title = "County Documents";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_polls:
            fragment = new PollsFragment();
            title = "Polls";
            break;
        case R.id.nav_faq_and_feedback:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.nav_contacts:
            fragment = new Contacts();
            title = "Contacts";
            break;

    }


    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    // set the toolbar title
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(title);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(int itemId, int tagId, int countyId) {
    Intent slideintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            NewsSlidePagerActivity.class);

    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_ITEM_ID, itemId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_TAG_ID, tagId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_COUNTY_ID, countyId);

    startActivity(slideintent);

}

@Override
public void onAvailableCountiesChanged(ArrayList<FilterSpinner> counties) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got list of available video topics, " + counties.size()
            + " items.");

    // make a sorted list of topics
    ArrayList<FilterSpinner> sortedTopics = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
    sortedTopics.addAll(counties);
    Collections.sort(sortedTopics, null);

    Spinner topicsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.news_filter_spinner_county);
    mCounties.clear();
    if (topicsSpinner != null) {
        ArrayList<FilterSpinner> items2 = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
        int positionToSelect = -1;
        items2.add(new FilterSpinner(0, getString(R.string.all_counties)));
        mCounties.add(new FilterSpinner(0, "")); // represents
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTopics.size(); i++) {
            items2.add(new FilterSpinner(sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(),
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemName()));
            mCounties.add(new FilterSpinner(
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(), sortedTopics.get(i)
                    .getItemName()));

        }
        populateSpinner(topicsSpinner, items2);
        topicsSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                               View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position >= 0 && position < mCounties.size()) {
                            onCountySelected(mCounties.get(position)
                                    .getItemId());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    }
                });

        if (positionToSelect > 0) {
            topicsSpinner.setSelection(positionToSelect);
            mCountyToRestore = "";
        }
    } else {
        // should not happen...
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Topics spinner not found (Activity not initialized yet?).");
    }

}

@Override
public void onAvailableSectorsChanged(ArrayList<FilterSpinner> sectors) {
    ArrayList<FilterSpinner> sortedSectors = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
    sortedSectors.addAll(sectors);
    Collections.sort(sectors);

    Spinner sectorsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.news_filter_spinner_sector);
    mSectors.clear();
    if (sectorsSpinner != null) {
        ArrayList<FilterSpinner> sectorItems = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
        int positionToSelect = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedSectors.size(); i++) {
            sectorItems.add(new FilterSpinner(sortedSectors.get(i)
                    .getItemId(), sortedSectors.get(i).getItemName()));
            mSectors.add(new FilterSpinner(
                    sortedSectors.get(i).getItemId(), sortedSectors.get(i)
                    .getItemName()));

        }
        populateSpinner(sectorsSpinner, sectorItems);

        sectorsSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                               View view, int position, long id) {
                        onSectorSelected(mSectors.get(position).getItemId());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
    }

}

private void populateSpinner(Spinner spinner, ArrayList<FilterSpinner> items) {
    MySpinnerAdapter adapter1 = new MySpinnerAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, items);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
}


private void onCountySelected(int county) {
    if (mSelectedCounty == county) {
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "County selected: " + county);
    JobsFragment frag = (JobsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if (frag == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "PostsListFragment fragment not found.");
        return;
    }
    mSelectedCounty = county;

    frag.setFilterAndReload(mSelectedCounty, mSelectedSector);
}

private void onSectorSelected(int sector) {
    if (mSelectedSector == sector) {
        return;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Sector selected: " + sector);
    JobsFragment frag = (JobsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

    if (frag == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "PostsListFragment fragment not found.");
        return;
    }

    mSelectedSector = sector;

    frag.setFilterAndReload(mSelectedCounty, mSelectedSector);
}

@Override
public void onJobSelected(int itemId, int countyId, int tagId, String title) {
    Intent slideintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            JobsSlidePagerActivity.class);

    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_ITEM_ID, itemId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_TAG_ID, tagId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_COUNTY_ID, countyId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_ITEM_TITLE, title);

    startActivity(slideintent);
}

@Override
public void onTenderItemSelected(int itemId, int tagId, int countyId,
                                 String title) {
    Intent slideintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            NewsSlidePagerActivity.class);

    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_ITEM_ID, itemId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_TAG_ID, tagId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_COUNTY_ID, countyId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_ITEM_TITLE, title);

    startActivity(slideintent);

}

@Override
public void onAvailableCountyDocsCountiesChanged(
        ArrayList<FilterSpinner> counties) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got list of available video topics, " + counties.size()
            + " items.");
    // make a sorted list of topics
    ArrayList<FilterSpinner> sortedTopics = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
    sortedTopics.addAll(counties);
    Collections.sort(sortedTopics, null);

    Spinner topicsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.county_docs_county_filter);
    mCounties.clear();
    if (topicsSpinner != null) {
        ArrayList<FilterSpinner> items2 = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
        int positionToSelect = -1;
        items2.add(new FilterSpinner(0, getString(R.string.all_counties)));
        mCounties.add(new FilterSpinner(0, "")); // represents
        // "All counties"
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTopics.size(); i++) {
            items2.add(new FilterSpinner(sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(),
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemName()));
            mCounties.add(new FilterSpinner(
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(), sortedTopics.get(i)
                    .getItemName()));

        }
        populateSpinner(topicsSpinner, items2);
        topicsSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                               View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position >= 0 && position < mCounties.size()) {
                            onDocsCountyCountySelected(mCounties.get(
                                    position).getItemId());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    }
                });

        if (positionToSelect > 0) {
            topicsSpinner.setSelection(positionToSelect);
            mCountyToRestore = "";
        }
    } else {
        // should not happen...
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Topics spinner not found (Activity not initialized yet?).");
    }
}

private void onDocsCountyCountySelected(int county) {
    if (mSelectedCounty == county) {
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "County selected: " + county);
    CountyDocsFragment frag = (CountyDocsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if (frag == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "CountyDocsFragment fragment not found.");
        return;
    }
    mSelectedCounty = county;

    frag.setFilterAndReload(mSelectedCounty);
}

@Override
public void onBlogItemSelected(int itemId, int tagId, int countyId) {
    Intent slideintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            NewsSlidePagerActivity.class);

    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_ITEM_ID, itemId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_TAG_ID, tagId);
    slideintent.putExtra(NewsSlidePagerActivity.ARG_COUNTY_ID, countyId);

    startActivity(slideintent);

}

@Override
public void onAvailableMyCountyChanged(ArrayList<FilterSpinner> counties) {
    // make a sorted list of topics
    ArrayList<FilterSpinner> sortedTopics = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
    sortedTopics.addAll(counties);
    Collections.sort(sortedTopics, null);

    Spinner topicsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_county_info_county_filter);
    mCounties.clear();
    if (topicsSpinner != null) {
        ArrayList<FilterSpinner> items2 = new ArrayList<FilterSpinner>();
        int positionToSelect = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTopics.size(); i++) {
            items2.add(new FilterSpinner(sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(),
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemName()));
            mCounties.add(new FilterSpinner(
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(), sortedTopics.get(i)
                    .getItemName()));

        }
        populateSpinner(topicsSpinner, items2);
        topicsSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                               View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position >= 0 && position < mCounties.size()) {
                            onMyCountyInfoSelected(mCounties.get(position)
                                    .getItemId());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    }
                });

        if (positionToSelect > 0) {
            topicsSpinner.setSelection(positionToSelect);
            mCountyToRestore = "";
        }
    } else {
        // should not happen...
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Topics spinner not found (Activity not initialized yet?).");
    }

}

@Override
public void onAvailableCountyInfoChanged(
        ArrayList<FilterSpinner> countyinfotypes) {
    // make a sorted list of topics
    ArrayList<FilterSpinner> sortedTopics = new ArrayList<>();
    sortedTopics.addAll(countyinfotypes);
    Collections.sort(sortedTopics, null);

    Spinner topicsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_county_info_county_info_types_filter);
    mSectors.clear();
    if (topicsSpinner != null) {
        ArrayList<FilterSpinner> items2 = new ArrayList<>();
        int positionToSelect = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedTopics.size(); i++) {
            items2.add(new FilterSpinner(sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(),
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemName()));
            mSectors.add(new FilterSpinner(sortedTopics.get(i).getItemId(),
                    sortedTopics.get(i).getItemName()));

        }
        populateSpinner(topicsSpinner, items2);
        topicsSpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                               View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (position >= 0 && position < mSectors.size()) {
                            onMyCountyInfoTypesSelected(mSectors.get(
                                    position).getItemId());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    }
                });

        if (positionToSelect > 0) {
            topicsSpinner.setSelection(positionToSelect);
            mCountyToRestore = "";
        }
    } else {
        // should not happen...
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Topics spinner not found (Activity not initialized yet?).");
    }

}

private void onMyCountyInfoSelected(int county) {
    if (mSelectedCounty == county) {
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "County selected:MyCountyInfoFragment: " + county);
    MyCountyInfoFragment frag = (MyCountyInfoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if (frag == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MyCountyInfoFragment fragment not found.");
        return;
    }
    mSelectedCounty = county;

    frag.setFilterAndReload(mSelectedCounty, mSelectedCountyInfoType);
}

private void onMyCountyInfoTypesSelected(int info_type) {
    if (mSelectedCountyInfoType == info_type) {
        return;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Sector selected:MyCountyInfoFragment: " + info_type);
    MyCountyInfoFragment frag = (MyCountyInfoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if (frag == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MyCountyInfoFragment fragment not found.");
        return;
    }
    mSelectedCountyInfoType = info_type;

    frag.setFilterAndReload(mSelectedCounty, mSelectedCountyInfoType);
}

@Override
public void onPollSelected(String pollUri) {
    Intent slideintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            ViewPollActivity.class);

    slideintent.putExtra(ViewPollActivity.POLL_URI, pollUri);

    startActivity(slideintent);

}



@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            displayView(item.getItemId());
        }
    }, NAVDRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back again to exit",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}}
```

The layout file that contains the toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<!--<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
<!--android:id="@+id/fab"-->
<!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"-->
<!--android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"-->
<!--android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The theme in other activities:

```
 <style name="DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColour </item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColour </item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post your activity code too.

Comment: @ParagKadam I have edited the code to include the activity

Comment: Where does the `toolbar` come from ,can you also share layout file that contains the `toolbar`.

Comment: @ParagKadam I have included the file

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732952/how-to-enable-homeasup-or-call-setdisplayhomeasupenabled-on-standalone-toolbar

Comment: @piotrek1543 On other activities, the ActionBar is present....it is only absent in MainActivity

Comment: go to manifest file and check if your main  activity  has different theme than others

Comment: @piotrek1543 yes the MainActivity has a different theme from other activities which is:

I have included this other theme in the original post

Comment: so change it like others, run the app and tell me if it's ok

Comment: @piotrek1543 when I use this other theme (updated in the original post) I get this error  


"This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead."

I know I can solve that by adding these two lines in my theme but then that takes me back to my original problem (the ActionBar disappears when I generate a signed APK):

 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98791/discussion-between-piotrek1543-and-lawrence-macharia).

Comment: Strange problem, if I find out why it happens, I would answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a solution to the above problem I was facing...I replaced my style definition with Android Studio default

In styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And then in styles.xml(v21)

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I had imported the project from Eclipse and I was trying to work with the styles the same way I was doing in Eclipse.

Everything is now Okay.